# Correct pattern for a MustOverride method that accepts narrowed types in implementations

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, overriding

I'm writing some software that automates data gathering from experiments, and needed some help expressing the relationship between my business objects.

I have a type called `Experiment`, a type called `Sample`, and an unimplemented `RunOnSample` method in `Experiment` that should accept a derivative of the `Sample` type and fill data into it:

```
Public MustInherit Class Experiment
    Public Property TestDate As Date
    Public Property Experimenter As String

    Public MustOverride Sub RunOnSample(sample As Sample)
End Class

Public MustInherit Class Sample
    Public Property UnitLotCode As String
End Class
```

Neither of these types are actually instantiable, since I have different experiments (represented by subtypes of `Experiment`) that generate various kinds of data. Each experiment has a matching subtype of `Sample` that has properties to store the data generated by the experiment. Note that the base classes are necessary, since there are some properties common to all experiments, and some data that will be recorded for all samples.

For example, a `ThicknessExperiment` measures thickness data and scans a lot code, then fills this data out into a `ThicknessSample`:

```
Public Class ThicknessExperiment
    Public Overrides Sub RunOnSample(sample As ThicknessSample)
        Dim data = GetDataFromMeasurementDevice()

        sample.UnitLotCode = data.LotCode
        sample.Thickness = data.Thickness
    End Sub
End Class

Public MustInherit Class ThicknessSample
    Public Property Thickness As Single
End Class
```

The problem here is that the type of the parameter is unacceptable to the compiler; the implementation of `RunOnSample` must accept `Sample`, and not `ThicknessSample` (or any other subtype of `Sample`). Presumably this is because, had the compiler let me have my way, the derived experiment would no longer have the same interface as the parent class, which would be un-polymorphic.

The only way I can think of to approach this problem is to cast the argument to the appropriate subtype of `Sample` inside the method before using it. Is there a better way to implement what I am going for? Preferably an approach that maintains the strongly typed association of a `XYZExperiment.RunOnSample` method to a `XYZSample` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i would like to say that as a *personal preference* and from a *bit of experience* i learned not to use inheritance for code reuse or common properties, but rather only to benefit from polymorphism so i would extract those common data properties into a new class and use a dictionary for the varying properties then use delegation *(composition)* to store the data for a certain sample. Anyway, my suggested solution involves the use of generics so you can do something like this:

```
public abstract class Experiment<TSample>
            where TSample : Sample
        {
            private DateTime experimentDate;
            private string Experimenter;

            public abstract void RunOnSample(TSample sample);
        }

        public class ThicknessExperiment : Experiment<ThicknessSample>
        {

            public override void RunOnSample(ThicknessSample sample)
            {
                // sample.lotcode = "43";
                // sample.data1 = "343";
                // sample.data2 = "43";

            }
        }

        public abstract class Sample
        {
            public string lotcode;

        }

        public class ThicknessSample : Sample
        {
            public string data1;
            public string data2;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, this is a very good idea. I don't know why I didn't think of generics.